# iOS resize and move image mask with fingers

Tags: ios, resize, mask, masking, pinch

I am trying to resize and move mask on image with fingers. For moving the mask I need touch to move gesture and for resize I need to implement pinch-to-zoom gesture.

Generally I want to manipulate image mask with my fingers, not programatically.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer at the Apple's Developer page.

Comment: Do you have a link or maybe a title of the example you are referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Be more specific with your source. This is not helpful to anyone else.